# "AAA" before booking a segment (EnhancedAirbook) and issue ticket (AirTicket)

Tags: sabre

I'm trying make a search in one particular PCC and then jump to another PCC which is Change AAA before EnhancedAirBook.
 searching (Bargin Finder Max-BFM) from one particular PCC and jump in 'AAA' - ChangeContext to other PCC before booking - (EnhancedAirBook) & issuing ticket(AirTicket)

We already have the permission granted to jump in between the PCC's from Sabre.

I tried Change AAA - ChangeContext before booking - (EnhancedAirBook) but the service is failing with an error

Below are the request & response.

Request

```
`<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <m:MessageHeader xmlns:m="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
            <m:From>
                <m:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">info@test.com</m:PartyId>
            </m:From>
            <m:To>
                <m:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices3.sabre.com</m:PartyId>
            </m:To>
            <m:CPAId>YYYY</m:CPAId>
            <m:ConversationId>1555434991</m:ConversationId>
            <m:Service m:type="OTA">ContextChangeLLSRQ</m:Service>
            <m:Action>ContextChangeLLSRQ</m:Action>
            <m:MessageData>
                <m:MessageId>mid:1555434991</m:MessageId>
                <m:Timestamp>2019-04-16T17-16-31Z</m:Timestamp>
                <m:TimeToLive>2019-04-16T17-16-31Z</m:TimeToLive>
            </m:MessageData>
            <m:DuplicateElimination />
            <m:Description>ContextChangeLLSRQ</m:Description>
        </m:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESF!ICESMSL</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ContextChangeRQ Version="2.0.3">
            <ChangeAAA PseudoCityCode="xxxx" />
        </ContextChangeRQ>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`
```

Response

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header>
        <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
            <eb:From>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices3.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:From>
            <eb:To>
                <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">info@test.com</eb:PartyId>
            </eb:To>
            <eb:CPAId>YYYY</eb:CPAId>
            <eb:ConversationId>1555434991</eb:ConversationId>
            <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">ContextChangeLLSRQ</eb:Service>
            <eb:Action>ContextChangeLLSRS</eb:Action>
            <eb:MessageData>
                <eb:MessageId>9418687622788650624</eb:MessageId>
                <eb:Timestamp>2019-04-16T17:17:59</eb:Timestamp>
                <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:1555434991</eb:RefToMessageId>
            </eb:MessageData>
        </eb:MessageHeader>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESF!ICESMSLB</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <soap-env:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap-env:Client.Validation</faultcode>
            <faultstring>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <stl:ApplicationResults xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="NotProcessed">
                    <stl:Error timeStamp="2019-04-16T12:17:59-05:00" type="Validation">
                        <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                            <stl:Message>cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ContextChangeRQ'.</stl:Message>
                            <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
                        </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    </stl:Error>
                </stl:ApplicationResults>
            </detail>
        </soap-env:Fault>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing with the namespace ***xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"***

```
<soap:Body>
    <ContextChangeRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.0.3">
        <ChangeAAA PseudoCityCode="xxxx"/>
    </ContextChangeRQ>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to changeAAA but response

```
<Message>?FORMAT?</Message>
        <ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</ShortText>
```

bellow RQ

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sec="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:mes="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2002/11">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <sec:Security>
         <sec:BinarySecurityToken>Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTD!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!1575253138274!5391!13</sec:BinarySecurityToken>
      </sec:Security>
      <mes:MessageHeader mes:id="?" mes:version="?">
         <mes:From>
            <mes:PartyId >WebServiceClient</mes:PartyId>            
         </mes:From>
         <mes:To>
            <mes:PartyId >WebServiceSupplier</mes:PartyId>         
         </mes:To>
         <mes:CPAId>VN</mes:CPAId>
         <mes:ConversationId>fOV1LWT3EJIUnGC0Yh1</mes:ConversationId>
         <mes:Service ></mes:Service>
         <mes:Action>ContextChangeLLSRQ</mes:Action>
         <mes:MessageData>
            <mes:MessageId>mid:20001209-133003-2333@clientofsabre.com1</mes:MessageId>
            <mes:Timestamp>2019-06-15</mes:Timestamp>    
         </mes:MessageData>
      </mes:MessageHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <ContextChangeRQ Version="2.0.3" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ChangeAAA PseudoCityCode="xxxx"/>
        </ContextChangeRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please put answers in the answer section. Do no use it to put another question. If you have a question, post it separately.